# Is there an archive of man pages sorted by software version?

Tags: linux, man

Is there a published archive of every man page for every (or at least the most common) linux utilities across all the different versions of said utilities?

My use case is I'm trying to figure out when the `-status` argument was added to `openssl s_client`. I have it narrow down to between 1.0.1e and 1.0.1j by comparing man pages across different FreeBSD versions:

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=s_client&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE

But I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do that.

Q:  Is there a way to search for a man page for a particular utility archived by that software's version number?

Comment: For OpenSSL, thus not an answer to your Q, all release tars are available at https://www.openssl.org/source/old/ and since I have downloaded and self-built almost every release since ~2008, I have an 'archive' on my system from which I can tell you it was added to 1.0.0 at patch n and 1.0.1 at patch i. (To be clear, it was actually in the _code_ since 0.9.8, but omitted from the man page.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That is excellent information. I appreciate that. I suppose I'll leave the question unanswered for a bit longer though since it doesn't apply to all Linux utilities. But non the less, thank you.